# How to send Response type as a parameter to html file in python?

Tags: python, json, response, pyodbc, flask-restful

I am creating api in python flask. I am using SQL Server for database and got data successfully using a `SELECT` query and return the data in json format using jsonify of flask. `myapi.py` file is:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect, flash
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from flask import jsonify
import pyodbc

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app=flask_app)

# creating connection Object which will contain SQL Server Connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=TABRIZIYAN;'
                  'Database=market_DB;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

class ProductList(Resource):
    def get(self):  # will be used to fetch all record from tbl_product 
    try:
        cursor =conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Tbl_product")
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        resp = jsonify(results)
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

api.add_resource(ProductList , '/product')

if __name__ == '__main__':
flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run it on `http://localhost:5000/product`, I see :

```
[
     {
        "P_ID": 1,
        "title": "product1",
        "count": 100,
        "price": 1000,
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "P_ID": 2,
        "title": "Product2",
        "count": 12,
        "price": 2500,
        "active": false
    },
]
```

Now, I want to send `resp` as a parameter to `product.html` in  `app.py` file. My `app.py` file is :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for, request, redirect, flash, jsonify
import pyodbc
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/product')
def product():
    info = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/product') 
    return render_template('product.html', info=info)

if __name__=='__main__':
app.run(debug=True, port="8080")
```

and my `product.html` is:

```
{% block body %}
<body>
<h1>Products List</h1>

<table  style="text-align: center" width="15%" border="3px" bgcolor="#FFE4E1">
    <tr><td><a href='/add'>Add New Product</a></td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table style="text-align: center" width="50%" align="left" border= "3px solid black" border- 
 collapse= collapse bgcolor="#E0FFFF">
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Count </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Active </th>
        <th> Actions </th>
   </tr>
    {% for product in info %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{product[0]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[1]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[2]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[3]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[4]}} </td>
        <td> <a href='/edit/{{product[0]}}'>Edit</a> 
        <a href='/delete/{{product[0]}}' onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete?')">Delete</a> </td>

    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to display values of `resp` dictionary in `product.html` as a table using rest api but I don't know how can I send `info` as parameter to `product.html` becuase `info` type is `Response` and this my code doesn't run currectly. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

using Response Keyword to send multiple values

```
return Response({"res":resp},status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: ```resp``` is a list of dictionary. I want to call  ```get``` function in ```app.py``` and its response put to ```info```. Then send ```info``` as a parameter to ```product.html``` .